# How to make a straighttable evaluate unique ids from previous months and not include the same ids the next month in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Let's say that I have the following table

```
    Name    Tattoo  Month  Team
    Bob     No      Jan    Team1
    Kelly   No      Jan    Team1
    Andrew  Yes     Jan    Team1
    Bob     No      Feb    Team1
    Kelly   No      Feb    Team1
    Andrew  Yes     Feb    Team1
```

And the resulting straighttable that I want to create is this

```
Month    Tattoos_Team_1
Jan      1
Feb      0
```

In other words, if a person already had a tattoo the previous month, I don't want that same person to be included in the next month in the straighttable.

This is what my script code currently looks like:

```
Table1:
LOAD Distinct Name, 
     Tattoo, 
     if(Tattoo='Yes','TYes')as YesTattoo,
     Month, 
     Team,
     if(Team='Team1','Team 1') as Team_1,
     if(Team='Team2','Team 2') as Team_2,
     if(Team='Team3','Team 3') as Team_3
FROM
[Bok1.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels);
```

And in my straighttable i've set `Month` as dimension and `Count(Distinct {<YesTattoo>}Team_1)` as expression.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming people is not erasing their tattoos and that you will show your months in ascendent order, you can simply subtract the tattoos of the previous month:

```
Count(Distinct {<YesTattoo>}Team_1) - above([Tattoos_Team_1])
```